# Having issues trying to solve N Rook problem . Always get n*n solution and not N factorial

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get N ways of solves a N rook problem. The issue I am having is currently, I seem to get n*n solutions while it needs to be N! . Below is my code, I have written it in simple loops and functions, so it's quite long. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Note: Please ignore case for n = 2. I get some duplicates which I thought I would handle via JSON.stringify

```
var createMatrix = function (n) {
    var newMatrix = new Array(n);

    // build matrix
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      newMatrix[i] = new Array(n);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        newMatrix[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }

    return newMatrix;
  };

  var newMatrix = createMatrix(n);

  // based on rook position, greying out function 
  var collision = function (i, j) {
    var col = i;
    var row = j;

    while (col < n) {
      // set the row (i) to all 'a'
      col++;
      if (col < n) {
        if (newMatrix[col][j] !== 1) {
          newMatrix[col][j] = 'x';
        }
      }
    }

    while (row < n) {
      // set columns (j) to all 'a'
      row++;
      if (row < n) {
        if (newMatrix[i][row] !== 1) {
          newMatrix[i][row] = 'x';
        }
      }
    }

    if (i > 0) {
      col = i;
      while (col !== 0) {
        col--;
        if (newMatrix[col][j] !== 1) {
          newMatrix[col][j] = 'x';
        }
      }
    }
    if (j > 0) {
      row = j;
      while (row !== 0) {
        row--;
        if (newMatrix[i][row] !== 1) {
          newMatrix[i][row] = 'x';
        }
      }
    }
  };

  // checks position with 0 and sets it with Rook
  var emptyPositionChecker = function (matrix) {
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j] === 0) {
          matrix[i][j] = 1;
          collision(i, j);
          return true;
        }
      }
    }

    return false;
  };


  // loop for every position on the board
  loop1:
    for (var i = 0; i < newMatrix.length; i++) {
      var row = newMatrix[i];

      for (var j = 0; j < newMatrix.length; j++) {
        // pick a position for rook
        newMatrix[i][j] = 1;

        // grey out collison zones due to the above position
        collision(i, j);

        var hasEmpty = true;

        while (hasEmpty) {
          //call empty position checker
          if (emptyPositionChecker(newMatrix)) {
            continue;
          } else {
            //else we found a complete matrix, break
            hasEmpty = false;
            solutionCount++;
            // reinitiaze new array to start all over
            newMatrix = createMatrix(n);
            break;
          }
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: If you do a console.log of newMatrix as you add to solutionCount you'll see that some patterns are repeated, and (possibly) some patterns are not found.

Comment: I can understand some patterns repeating but I can't seem to understand how I would miss some combinations as I am looping through every position in the board

Comment: When I run your code with n=3 I seem to be missing xx1x1x1xx. Maybe I have copied your code wrong? Perhaps if you put up a fiddle we could check?

Comment: Thank you! I don't use jsfiddle much but here it is https://jsfiddle.net/bnf1aeto/ . Let me know if you can access it ?

Comment: Thanks - yes I see the fiddle but will not be able to have a closer look for a bit.

Comment: Hi, you aren't looping through every position on the board, you are looping through every starting position (for the first rook to be put down on [i][j]). When you have one solution for that you are satisfied and break out to the next starting position, thus missing some other positions. Do you want to continue with finding a solution with iteration? Recursion is a more normal way of solving this.

Comment: I have put up an answer so you can see what is going wrong. If it's useful you can mark it as such, but to get to the depths of the problem, and find an algorithm that will work in practice for a board of any size (iteration over all possible positions soon gets pretty enormous loop-wise) it's probably best to move to say [link]https://cs.stackexchange.com You have a problem with the algorithm, you don't have a Javascript problem..

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two underlying problems.

The first is that several copies of the same position are being found.

If we consider the case of N=3 and we visualise the positions by making the first rook placed red, the second placed green and the third to be placed blue, we get these three boards:
[image: 3 identical positions]

They are identical positions but will count as 3 separate ones in the given Javascript.

For a 3x3 board there are also 2 other positions which have duplicates. The gets the count of unique positions to 9 - 2 - 1 -1 = 5. But we are expecting N! = 6 positions.

This brings us to the second problem which is that some positions are missed. In the case of N=3 this occurs once when i===j==1 - ie the mid point of the board.

This position is reached:
[image: Reached]

This position is not reached:
[image: Not reached]

So now we have the number of positions that should be found as 9 - 2 - 1 - 1 +1;

There appears to be nothing wrong with the actual Javascript in as much as it is implementing the given algorithm. What is wrong is the algorithm which is both finding and counting duplicates and is missing some positions.

A common way of solving the N Rooks problem is to use a recursive method rather than an iterative one, and indeed iteration might very soon get totally out of hand if it's trying to evaluate every single position on a board of any size.

This question is probably best taken up on one of the other stackexchange sites where algorithms are discussed.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I figured it out a couple days back what the issue was and indeed came across the need for recursion. My recursion abilities are not great but would be great if you have any resource could point me to , to get a good handle on recursion?

Comment: I’ve had a quick look round and frankly there are some quite muddly articles out there, but a simple one is [link] https://codeburst.io/learn-and-understand-recursion-in-javascript-b588218e87ea  There’s also a JS rooks solution at [link] https://logicmason.com/2013/a-recursive-algorithm-for-generating-all-n-rooks-solutions-and-a-linear-time-n-queens-solution/ which isn’t too long within itself but I think is using a memorising function from the Lodash library to store interim results, so things get a bit more complex.